# Is there a way to listen for the NSApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicatonWillTerminate calls?

Tags: swift, notifications

My use case is that I have an object that needs to set itself up when the application starts and tears itself down when the application is about to exit. Currently I have a "setup" and "teardown" method that I call in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and `applicationWillTerminate` methods of the application delegate. However I find I'm following this pattern more and more so I'm getting a string of "setup" and "teardown" calls in the app delegate methods.

What I would like to do is formalize this some by having my objects automatically "register" themselves to listen to the app delegate methods. Obviously I could create the necessary infrastructure myself by defining a listener and a helper class that the delegate could subclass from to handle this.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way for my objects to register to receive the same notification that causes the app delegate methods to be called without having to actually reference the app delegate itself?

I had hoped that the following code would work, but it does not. I never get the "got it" message.

```
public override init() {
    super.init()
    print("!! registering, delegate=\(NSApplication.shared.delegate)")
    DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(
        NSApplication.shared,
        selector: #selector(self.myObservedEvent(notification:)),
        name: NSApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification,
        object: nil
        )
}

@objc func myObservedEvent(notification: Notification) {
    print("!!! got it")
}
```

I figure that either I'm doing something wrong in my registration and there may be a simple fix, or perhaps the `init` method is too soon to be able to perform the registration. (The app delegate is nil at the time this is called, which makes sense since my object is a property of the delegate object. And to answer the obvious question, yes my object is subclassed from `NSObject`.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was using the wrong notification centre, and passing the wrong object. The following code does what I wanted:

```
public override init() {
    super.init()
    print("!! registering, delegate=\(NSApplication.shared.delegate)")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.myObservedEvent(notification:)),
        name: NSApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification,
        object: nil
        )
}

@objc func myObservedEvent(notification: Notification) {
    print("!!! got it")
}
```